# how to use pyglet to play sound in a mayavi animation?

Tags: python, yield, pyglet, mayavi

I want to play sound using `pyglet` in a mayavi animation loop, but I found that `pyglet` worked not well with 'yield', which has to use in a mayavi animation. The situation is that, it just can't start a new loop when the sound played and animation done once, here are some of my codes, any ideas?

The `pyglet` can play sound in a for-loop, but can't use `yield`.

```
@mlab.animate(delay=delays)
def animate():
    f = mlab.gcf()
    while True:
        for i in range(frames_num): 
            # update sound
            sound = 'shiping/shiping_%d.wav'%i
            sound_adjust = pyglet.resource.media(sound, streaming=False)
            sound_adjust.play()

            # update scene
            print('Update scene >>', time.time())
            function_to_update_scene()
            # with out 'yield' it works well
            yield
animate()
```

Any other modules suggest can also be accepted. The matter is that I need to update sound quickly within 20ms.

Comment: It looks like you'll have to play the sound in a separate process, sending a "play now" order using [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) or something like it.

Comment: I am not familiar with multithreading, let me have a try. Thank you, Felipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I at last solved this by using `winsound` module. Using

```
winsound.PlaySound(sound, winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

to replace

```
sound_adjust = pyglet.resource.media(sound, streaming=False) 
sound_adjust.play()
```

to play defined sound asynchronously. Off course you have to `import winsound` at the very beginning.

Comment: Could you expand this answer, e.g. by explaining how did you solve it exactly, e.g. based on the code that you provided? It will greatly help others reproduce your solution.

Comment: If it solved your question, feel free to mark it as such (green tick on the answer). This will evidence to others that that particular answer answers your question. :)

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that. I'm new to stack overflow and not good at English :)